# How to get selector on click?

Tags: jquery, selector

I have simple `jQuery` script like:

```
jQuery('#template-custom-fields').on('click', '.custom-field-type-toggle-tax, .custom-field-type-toggle-discount', function(event){
    console.log(event); //  here i need to know what type it is? .custom-field-type-toggle-tax or .custom-field-type-toggle-discount
});
```

How to get selector inside the callback?

**UPDATE:**

I don't need to do any check here, i need to get current selector (there is 5 or 6) and add to current `active` class!

Comment: And why would you need the selector, you have `this` if you need to do something with the element ?

Comment: @adeneo i just want to know if it is possible to get the selector inside the callback

Comment: It's not, there used to be a `selector` property passed to jQuery event handlers that contained the selector, but I'm pretty sure that was removed several years ago.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `this` to get the element that triggered the event:

```
jQuery('#template-custom-fields').on('click', '.custom-field-type-toggle-tax, .custom-field-type-toggle-discount', function(event){
    console.dir(this);
    if($(this).hasClass("custom-field-type-toggle-tax")){ 
        //do what you need here
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check like this:

```
if ($(this).is('.custom-field-type-toggle-tax')) {

}
```